# Django: ManyToMany filter matching to any item in a list

Tags: django

On a model `blog` I have a `ManyToMany` field called `permissionGroups`, which as the name suggests is a list of groups allowed to access something.

```
class blog(models.Model):    
    permissionGroups = models.ManyToManyField(groups, null=True, blank=True)
    ...
```

On another model `groups` I have a `ManyToMany` field called `allowedUsers` which again as the name suggests, is a list of users within that group.

```
class groups(models.Model):
    allowedUsers = models.ManyToManyField(User, null=True, blank=True)
    ...
```

So I want to be able to get all `groups` that the `currentUser` is in and match any one of those to any one of the `permissionGroups` of a specific `blog`.

I hope all that was clear,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the final data you are looking for? A list of groups? A boolean "Can edit / can not edit"?

To check if a user belongs to a group that belongs to a blog, you can do this:
`user.groups_set.filter(blog=blog)` This is the equivalent of checking if a user can edit said blog.

If you want a list of blogs that a user can edit, you can do this:
`blog.objects.filter(permissiongroups__in=user.groups_set.all())`

Somehow thinking of your models was a mind bender.